# Spring - Springboot controller GET requests with default parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Springboot controller with two GET endpoints:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
class MyController {

    fun getFoo(
        @RequestParam("x", required = false) x: Int = 0
    ) = ...

    fun getFoo(
        @RequestParam("x", required = true) x: Int,
        @RequestParam("y", required = true) y: Int
    ) = ...
```

The behaviour I want is that when called:

- `/foo` calls the first endpoint with an optional `x` param.
- `/foo?x=123` calls the first endpoint with a supplied `x` param.
- `/foo?x=123&y=456' calls the second endpoint with the supplied` x`and`y` params.

Currently I get an error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-20T13:11:24.732+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Parameter conditions \"x\" OR \"x, y\" not met for actual request parameters: ",
    "path": "/foo"
}
```

Any ideas how to determine a default endpoint when zero params are specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a [**params**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) in `@RequestMapping` or its variants(`@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping` etc).

eg.

```kotlin
@GetMapping(params=arrayOf("!x", "!y"))
fun getFoo()

@GetMapping(params=arrayOf("x", "!y"))
fun getFoo(
        @RequestParam("x", required = true) x: Int = 0

@GetMapping(params=arrayOf("x", "y"))
fun getFoo(
        @RequestParam("x", required = true) x: Int,
        @RequestParam("y", required = true) y: Int
```

Different params can be applied and identified on the same URI.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a `defaultValue` as a `String` in `@RequestParam`:

```
fun getFoo(
    @RequestParam(name = "x", required = false, defaultValue = "0") x: Int,
    @RequestParam(name = "y", required = false, defaultValue = "1") y: Int
) =
```

Spring will convert the `String` to whatever type you really want (`Int` in your case) using the same method as if you specified `x` as a parameter (same coercion, errors, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you want more then one mapping to the same url (lot of times it is a codesmell, but sometime it is necessary, you can do i twith filter params in `@GetMapping` or `@RequestMapping` annotations' params element.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
class MyController {

    @GetMapping(params = ["!y"])
    fun getFoo(
        @RequestParam("x", required = false) x: Int?
    ) = ...

    @GetMapping(params = ["x", "y"])
    fun getFoo(
        @RequestParam("x", required = true) x: Int,
        @RequestParam("y", required = true) y: Int
    ) = ...

}
```